# Nodejs xpath selector with element id and nested elements not working

Tags: node.js, xpath

I have this html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="lang-ru">
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="content">
    root
    <div>first</div>
    <div>second</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Using this selector returns the three nested elements as expected: `//*[@id="content"]/*`

but trying to apply this selector to return only the first nested div: `//*[@id="content"]/div[1]` and the return nodes list is empty

this selector to return both divs not working neither: `//*[@id="content"]/div`

How can I get the first nested div containing `first`, and how can I have all the nested divs and no other elements like the `p`.

[Here is the problem](https://repl.it/@lorraul/AssuredTrustingInterchangeability)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you bind `<html>` to a namespace `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`. Removing this attribute makes it work.

Alternatively, you can tell `xpath` to use this namespace like this:

```
const select = xpath.useNamespaces({mynamespace: "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"});
const nodes = select('//mynamespace:div', doc);
```

Comment: this will select all the divs, not just the first nested one. Tried with `//mynamespace:*[@id="content"]/div` and still getting error.

Comment: It was an example, what you want would be `//*[@id="content"]/mynamespace:div[1]`. `*` does not need a namespace, but `div` does: namespaces define tags.